# asp.net mvc viewmodel getting error public definition for getenumerator

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can get my Products model to my view ok. but I need to pass it in a ViewModel so I can interact with data from several models. When I bind my view to ProductPageViewModel then I get the "no public definition for GetEnumerator" error. I have tried all manner of IEnumerable options and cannot find the right combination.

I included controller and view that work when the view is bound to the model.

The full error is

> CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type   JaniesWebLive.ViewModel.ProductPageViewModel' because 
>    JaniesWebLive.ViewModel.ProductPageViewModel' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Triggered at `@foreach (var item in Model)`

Products.cs

```
public class Products 
{
    [Key]
    public int WpId { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string WpProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProdDescShort { get; set; }
    public string ProdDescLong { get; set; }
    public string ProductMedium { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price1 { get; set; }
}
```

ProductPageViewModel.cs

```
public class ProductPageViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Products> Products { get; set; }
    public Contact Contacts { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    /*more models to be added */
}
```

ProductsController.cs

```
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    public ActionResult ShortList(string prodname)
    {
        var products = db.DbProducts.Where(m => m.Category == "homepage");
        var model = new ViewModel.ProductPageViewModel
        {
            Products = products,
            Message = "Thanks for your business! "
            /* more models to be added  */
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

ShortList.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<JaniesWebLive.ViewModel.ProductPageViewModel>

   @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <p><img class="product-image" src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductMedium) /></p><br />
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WpProductId)</h3>
            <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price1)</h5>
            <h6>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdDescShort)</h6>
            <p class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdDescLong)</p>
            <p>
                <button class="text-right btn btn-link">SHORT LIST</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
 }
```

Working controller and view

```
public ActionResult LongList(string prodname)
{
    var model = db.DbProducts.Where(m => m.Category == "homepage");
    return View(model);
}
```

LongList.cshtml

```
@model JaniesWebLive.Models.Products

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <p><img class="product-image" src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductMedium) /></p>
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WpProductId)</h3>
            <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price1)</h5>
            <h6>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdDescShort)</h6>
            <p class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdDescLong)</p>
            <p>
                <button class="text-right btn btn-link">LONG LIST</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Your `LongList.cshtml` file has the model as a single `Products` - you cannot loop through a single object

Comment: `@model JaniesWebLive.Models.Products` expects single `Products` - not a collection of `Products`. If you want to use a collection just change to `@model IEnumerable<JaniesWebLive.Models.Products>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change the view to something like

```
@model JaniesWebLive.ViewModel.ProductPageViewModel

   @foreach (var item in Model.Products )
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <p><img class="product-image" src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductMedium) /></p><br />
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.WpProductId)</h3>
            <h5>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price1)</h5>
            <h6>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdDescShort)</h6>
            <p class="text-center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProdDescLong)</p>
            <p>
                <button class="text-right btn btn-link">SHORT LIST</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
 }
```

since upr view model is a single object which contain a list property you need to itterate the property not the whole model

Comment: Thank you Rahul. I knew it was something small. Didn't expect that small. I'm making progress again.